# Using JSON with Material UI nested menus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to bind the data to the MenuItems at the nested menu level. I can successfully map the data to populate the main levels, but the submenus are giving me an error.

My JSON looks like this:

```
const languages = [
    {
        name: 'English',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/uk.png',
        link: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'Español',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/Spain.png',
        link: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'Français',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/France.png',
        link: ''
    }
];
```

I am saving the submenu in a const so I can use it in the render. (I believe this is my  problem area but not sure what I need to do)

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false,
            open: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { colorOption } = this.props;

        //the code inside this const will work if I insert it inside my IconMenu. But it doesn't work inside the menuItems property which should be able to hold MenuItem objects    
        const languageMenu = {languages.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={index}
                className={classnames('menu-item', {
                    'bg-color-medlight': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0,
                    'bg-color-meddark': ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0
                })}
                primaryText={languages[index].name}
                style={{userMenuItem}}
                leftIcon={
                    <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                }/>
        ))}

        return(
        <div style={{zIndex:2}}>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <IconMenu
                            className="user"
                            iconButtonElement={
                                <RaisedButton style={ImgIconButtonStyle}><PersonalMenuIcon/></RaisedButton>
                            }
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                            targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}>

                            <MenuItem
                                className={classnames('menu-item', {
                                    'bg-color-medlight': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0,
                                    'bg-color-meddark': ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0
                                })}
                                primaryText="English"
                                rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
                                style={{userMenuItem}}
                                leftIcon={
                                    <img className="flag" src="./assets/images/flags/uk.png"/>
                                }
                                menuItems={{languageMenu}}
                                />
                        </IconMenu>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    } 

}
```

In a perfect world, a regular nested menu looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import Download from 'material-ui/svg-icons/file/file-download';
import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-drop-right';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';

/**
 * Example of nested menus within an IconMenu.
 */
const IconMenuExampleNested = () => (
  <IconMenu
    iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
  >
    <MenuItem
      primaryText="Copy & Paste"
      rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
      menuItems={[
        <MenuItem primaryText="Cut" />,
        <MenuItem primaryText="Copy" />,
        <Divider />,
        <MenuItem primaryText="Paste" />,
      ]}
    />

    <MenuItem
      primaryText="Case Tools"
      rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
      menuItems={[
        <MenuItem primaryText="UPPERCASE" />,
        <MenuItem primaryText="lowercase" />,
        <MenuItem primaryText="CamelCase" />,
        <MenuItem primaryText="Propercase" />,
      ]}
    />

  </IconMenu>
);

export default IconMenuExampleNested;
```

And the error I am getting is

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: 
>       C:/xampp/htdocs/ScalaCMReact/src/components/Header/UserMenu.js: Unexpected token, expected , (109:33)

```
107 |       const { colorOption } = this.props;
108 | 
109 |       const languageMenu = {languages.map((item, index) => (
    |                                      ^
110 |           <MenuItem
111 |               key={index}
112 |               className={classnames('menu-item', {
```

> @ ./src/components/Header/index.js 23:16-37
>      @ ./src/routes/app/components/MainApp.js
>      @ ./src/routes/app/index.js
>      @ ./src/client.js
>      @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8000/ webpack/hot/only-dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./client.js

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seems like valid javascript

```
const languageMenu = {languages.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={index}
                className={classnames('menu-item', {
                    'bg-color-medlight': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0,
                    'bg-color-meddark': ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0
                })}
                primaryText={languages[index].name}
                style={{userMenuItem}}
                leftIcon={
                    <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                }/>
        ))}
```

If you are trying to create an array of arrays then the outer brackets should be `[]`. If it's an object which has a property which contains the array of MenuItem's then

```
const languageMenu = {languages: languages.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={index}
                className={classnames('menu-item', {
                    'bg-color-medlight': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0,
                    'bg-color-meddark': ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0
                })}
                primaryText={languages[index].name}
                style={{userMenuItem}}
                leftIcon={
                    <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                }/>
        ))}
```

If you want to set the languageMenu to a react element then

```
const languageMenu = <div>
{languages.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={index}
                className={classnames('menu-item', {
                    'bg-color-medlight': ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0,
                    'bg-color-meddark': ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'].indexOf(colorOption) >= 0
                })}
                primaryText={languages[index].name}
                style={{userMenuItem}}
                leftIcon={
                    <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                }/>
        ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mukesh, That fixed the initial error but the error I'm getting now says `Failed prop type: Invalid prop "menuItems" supplied to "MenuItem", expected a ReactNode.` and when I click on the menu I get one more error that says `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {languageMenu}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of "MenuItem".`

Comment: This is very related to what you were saying, but I tried injecting inside [ ] and kept getting errors

Comment: That's because `menuItem` props is expecting a react node and you are sending it an object which it tries to render. I don't know the Material UI library works. But you probably want to wrap the array of submenus in a div

Comment: I have added another option for languageMenu, which should take care of the error. But i don't know if it will give the output you want

Comment: Wrapping a div around them didn't do anything either. I can't manually input these. Well, I could, but I need to have them in a json so I can manipulate them better. The chosen language will be shown on other elements and eventually translate the app.

Comment: YESSSSSS!!!!! That did it! I had to use single { } instead of double {{ }} and your cod worked wihtout errors! Thanks man!

Comment: By the way, I have a consequent problem related to this but since it's a different question alltogether, I created another question instead here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090322/changing-the-value-of-an-element-onclick-in-reactjs. If you can help me out there I will appreciate it bud.Thanks a lot