# Changing the value of an element onclick in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI submenu being populated from a json. The Main menu item holding this submenu array will be changed according to what is being selected. See image below

[image]

The Main menu item holding the submenus looks like this

```
    <MenuItem
        primaryText={this.state.selectedLanguage.name}
        rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
        style={{userMenuItem}}
        leftIcon={
            <img className="flag" src={this.state.selectedLanguage.icon}/>
        }
        menuItems={languageMenu} //see below
    />
```

The nested menus are coming from here

```
    const languageMenu =
        <div>
            {languages.map((item, index) => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={index}
                    onClick={this.onLanguageChange}
                    primaryText={languages[index].name}
                    style={{userMenuItem}}
                    leftIcon={
                        <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                    }/>
            ))}
        </div>
```

And ultimately, the data is stored in a json like this

```
const languages = [
    {
        name: 'English',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/uk.png',
        link: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'Español',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/Spain.png',
        link: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'Français',
        icon: './assets/images/flags/France.png',
        link: ''
    }
 ...
];
```

In my poor understanding of React, I created an initial value for the slected language in the constructor state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {          
        selectedLanguage:{
            name:"English",
            icon:"./assets/images/flags/uk.png",
        },
    }
}
```

and a function that will handle the changing (this is my problem area, I'm sure)

```
onLanguageChange = () => this.setState(
    {
        selectedLanguage: this.state.selectedLanguage.name,
    }
);
```

I need to build this `onChange()` function correctly to alter the state based on the submenu clicked. This will give me the groundwork to build other properties that will trigger a translate feature on click as well

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Binding state to MainMenu button like how do you do it in LanguageMenu `<img className="flag" src={this.state.selectedLanguage.icon}/>` when state change, notify and it change. Read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

Comment: @botika I changed a few things around. I was able to initiate the value by the state, so that's good because it now reads the state. I can't figure out how to build the onLanguageChange() so that it changes the state values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action needs a parameter - the new language:

```
onLanguageChange = languageName => this.setState({
    selectedLanguage: languageName
});
```

and you need to pass it from `onClick`:

```
{languages.map((language, index) => (
    <MenuItem
         key={index}
         onClick={() => this.onLanguageChange(language.name)}
         primaryText={language.name}
         style={{userMenuItem}}
         leftIcon={
             <img className="flag" src={language.icon}/>
         }
    />
))}
```

I am not sure if you want to store `language` in your state or just the `name`. Both ways have their uses.

Comment: This cleared up my submenus. It first said language is not defined which I get it because I dont have language anywhere so I used languages (the name of my json data but this resulted in a blank output in the submenus

Comment: By the way, the menuitem you posted is the submenu list building a repeater with all the languages in the data and dynamically creating that many menuitems. The click event should take place here but the one that needs to change is the MenuItem in my first block which is the parent menu. The image would give you a visual. Sorry if my code seems unclear. I was trying to avoid putting too much code on here

Comment: @LOTUSMS The `language` is the first parameter of `map`, which you originally had as `item`. It doesn't matter where your `state` is read or stored, it can be used by both your components. Maybe you want to the action to the parent component and keep the state there?

Comment: AH! My appologies, I missed that little detail. Ok, the language not defined error went away, but not, when I click on a submenu (i.e portuguese) the main menu is blank. No Errors, It just not receiving the new values. Could it be the onClick() is not updating the state? The main menu is reading from the state.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Maybe you want to pass the whole `language` object to state? e.g. `this.onLanguageChange(language)`? That's what I was not sure about.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
const languages = [...]


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {          
        selectedLanguage: 0
    }
}

onLanguageChange = (index) => this.setState({ selectedLanguage: index });

const mainMenu =    
    <MenuItem
            primaryText={languages[this.state.selectedLanguage].name}
            rightIcon={<ArrowDropRight />}
            style={{userMenuItem}}
            leftIcon={
                <img className="flag" src={languages[this.state.selectedLanguage].icon}/>
            }
            menuItems={languageMenu} //see below
    />

const languageMenu =
    <div>
        {languages.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={index}
                onClick={this.onLanguageChange(index)}
                primaryText={languages[index].name}
                style={{userMenuItem}}
                leftIcon={
                    <img className="flag" src={languages[index].icon}/>
                }/>
        ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: I updated my code in my orginal question. I don't know if you noticed that before. But the state has both name & icon initiated values there and are being passed to the main menu item. All I need now is for the oinClick to update the state values based on the answer from Sulthan.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one s

Comment: Sulthan answer got it working. But you did help me understand the initial build.  I appreciate it +1

Comment: But is not necessary pass the object to the state when you already have it as a global instance, you are duplicating instances. You're welcome

Comment: I will take a look at it. ;)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. It still buggy. Sorry man.

Comment: Now, just fixed selectedLanguageIndex for selectedLanguage in the state definition.

Comment: Sorry man, that gave me over 10K errors with the state. Don't worry about it. Thanks for everything. Sulthan answers worked. The important thing is that is working :)